Adaptation of the Medical Transformer for Wound Segmentation with Multiple Classes
I'm using Medical Transformer(https://github.com/jeya-maria-jose/Medical-Transformer) to segment wounds, but I'd like to adapt it to segment three different classes: wounds, an additional mark and the background. The model on github seems to have some issues for parameterizing the problem in multi-classes, but I'm having trouble understanding how to apply them in this specific case.
My labels use different colors for each class I want to target, because I want to calculate individual metrics for each of them. Below is an example of a label.

The wound is shown in blue.
One of my problems is figuring out where to set the color parameters.
Could someone help me with this adaptation for multiple classes?
